# How to remove a single edge of a polygon from Google Map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(
  this.poly, //currently selected polygon
  "mouseup",
  (event) => {
    if (this.insidePolygon(event.latLng)) {
      const path = this.poly.getPaths().getAt(event.path);
        if (event?.vertex >= 0) { //returns true if vertex is being dragged
          path.removeAt(event.vertex); // removes the current vertex
        } else if (event?.edge >= 0) { //returns true if edge is being dragged
          path.removeAt(event.edge); // does not remove the current edge
        }
    } else {
      this.calcAreaAndLatlng();
    }
  }
);
```

I have multiple polygons inside google map. I am trying to use **mouseup** event to drag and edit a polygon. I do not want my polygons to overlap. That's why I am using `insidePolygon` function which returns true if current polygon overlaps any other polygons. So when the function returns true, I use `path.removeAt(event.vertex)` to remove the ***vertex*** that was trying to overlap. But the problem begins when I try to drag ***edge*** instead of ***vertex***.  Then the `path.removeAt(event.edge)` does not work even though both `event.vertex` and `event.edge` return the index of vertex and edge respectively.  Is there any way to remove the edge like I removed the vertex?

Comment: Do you need to maybe reset the polygon's path to your new path, e.g. after you do `path.removeAt(event.edge);` add `this.poly.setPath(path)`

Comment: @duncan `path.removeAt(event.edge)` is not working. And `this.poly.setPath(path)` is not updating the path with or without `path.removeAt(event.edge)`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but without seeing your full code that shows us what `this.polygon` and `this.insidePolygon` look like, it's hard to diagnose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { width:800px; height:640px }
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    var MapClass = class {
        constructor() {
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: {lat: 51.476706, lng: 0},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
        }
        
        drawPentagon() {
            var coords = [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.474821, -0.001935),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.474647, 0.003966),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.477708, 0.004073),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.479753, 0.000468),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.477654, -0.002192)
            ];
            
            this.poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 10,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: this.map,
                draggable: true,
                editable: true
            });
        }
        
        addEventListeners() {
            window.google.maps.event.addListener(
                this.poly,
                "mouseup",
                (event) => {
                    if (this.insidePolygon(event.latLng)) {
                        const path = this.poly.getPaths().getAt(event.path);
                        if (event?.vertex >= 0) { //returns true if vertex is being dragged
                            path.removeAt(event.vertex); // removes the current vertex
                        } else if (event?.edge >= 0) { //returns true if edge is being dragged
                            path.removeAt(event.edge); // does not remove the current edge
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.calcAreaAndLatlng();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        
        insidePolygon(latLng) {
            console.log('insidePolygon', latLng);
            return true;
        }
        
        calcAreaAndLatlng() {
            console.log('calcAreaAndLatlng');
        }
    };
    
    function initialize() {
        var map = new MapClass();
        
        map.drawPentagon();
        map.addEventListeners();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried posting this as a runnable code snippet but kept getting security warnings from  Google Maps about trying to attach an event listener, not sure why

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. Not sure if it has something to with my `this.poly`. Now, I am trying to solve this issue using a different approach, I will let you know if I can solve this issue. If possible, please share your jsfiddle link.